# can i do this or how can i do this awk + sort?

Tags: shell, awk

```
cat file_outunique.out | awk '{ print $1, $2}' | sort $2 -u > ledernier.out
```

I want to output $1 and $2 for the 1st iteration of $2

Do you have any suggestions about this?

I've tried to change the syntax but I don't know if I can do it. Can i do this? How?

Input

```
sjffszh dgfeg7754
zezrlgk 544ad4z5g
qjiofzo 544ad4z5g
zlfkpif 546787438
zfkozfk 446787466
lfjzfoj dgfeg7754
kfkjzfj dgfeg7754
```

Output

```
sjffszh dgfeg7754
zezrlgk 544ad4z5g
zlfkpif 546787438
zfkozfk 446787466
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ? Give some sample input and expected output.

Comment: Just save the output that you posted in a file and you're done

Comment: i had 6k lines i cant

Comment: Umm @Julessh, you shouldn't change your question like that, you should ask another one.

Comment: i cant post an other one today

Comment: Please take the [tour](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) and read https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/asking-rate-limited; if you improve your original question here (without changing it so much it's no longer the same question), it may get upvoted which will contribute towards lifting the rate limit. This may feel pointless, but it will help you get better answers! And welcome to Unix.SE.

Answer (score 2):

Just count the occurrences of the second field in `awk`:

```
awk '!c[$2]++' file_outunique.out > ledernier.out
```

(assuming you want the first occurrence, despite your output's file name).

Comment: The question is not clear, however [it seems like](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/210206/can-i-do-this-or-how-can-i-do-this-awk-sort#comment355694_210214) OP wanted to sort the input file based on the second field deleting the lines in which this is not unique.

Comment: @kos: That's not what the sample output indicates.

Comment: @kos I had checked, the `awk` approach produces exactly the requested output, which isn't sorted.

Comment: Yes, indeed your answer is fine per what has been given, however judging from OP's comment to Govind Kailas' answer (and from OP's `cat file_outunique.out | awk '{ print $1, $2}' | sort $2 -u > ledernier.out ` attempt) it seems like the real goal is to also sort everything based on the second field. In any case upvoted since the question is unclear and it's very valuable in order to produce the requested output.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly do sort by the 2nd column.

`sort -k 2 -u file_outunique.out > ledernier.out`